# What would happen if I set up an amateur radio station in Canada without entering Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, radio

I have a US amateur radio license. I do not have a passport or Canadian amateur radio certificate. If I went near the border but stayed on the US side, set up an amateur radio station on a wheeled cart, enabled VOX (so I could talk on the radio without touching it), used a stick to push the cart into Canada, and began talking on the radio, am I subject to either US or Canadian amateur radio regulations?

Answer (score 4):

A little poking around [amateur](http://www.arrl.org/us-amateurs-operating-overseas) [radio](https://www.rac.ca/operating/canada-united-states-reciprocal-operating-agreement/) sites will find (from the second link):

> In 1952, Canada and the United States signed a Reciprocal Operating Agreement treaty. In the terms of the agreement, visiting Amateurs may operate in the host country in accordance with the rules and regulations of the host country.

You might want to check out https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions for further questions.

Comment: Which country would I be subject to the laws of? I'm not in Canada, so I don't think Canadian laws apply to me, but the station is not in the US, so I don't think US law applies either.

Comment: The station is in Canada, so "Under the terms of the agreement, the visitor must identify using his or her call sign followed by a call area suffix, e.g., VE3FRV/W9 or N9CFX/VE3". Where you are yelling from is irrelevant. The point of the agreement is to make the border pretty transparent to your operations.

Comment: Could I actually be prosecuted for a violation of Canadian regulations if i don't enter Canada? Of course if I ever went to Canada I could be prosecuted, but what if I never enter Canada after I do this? Could I be extradited for a violation of amateur radio regulations? (Note: I'm not actually considering doing this, I'm just curious what would happen if I did.)